# DispatchDraw method of View does not work

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to override a DispatchDraw method of View class to display something. My View class is below:

```
public class MyCustomButton : View
{
    private Paint colorPaint;
    public MyCustomButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        colorPaint = new Paint();
        colorPaint.Color = Color.Argb(0, 255, 0, 0);
    }
    protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.DrawText("aaa", 0, 0, colorPaint);
    }
}
```

And activity layout file (it is axml file in Xamarin) is below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Hw005_UiControls.MyCustomButton
        android:id="@+id/myBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My OnCreate method of MainActivity class is below:

```
...
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ButtonView5);
View view = FindViewById(Resource.Id.myBtn) as View;
view.Invalidate();
...
```

I trace those code, every line of code can be executed, but string "aaa" can be 
to shown. I use xamarin but for this case it is almost as same as java. So Is 
there someone could give me some tips to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DispatchDraw` is normally used if you are using a `ViewGroup` and need to render `View` children. Also the `Y` parameter of `DrawText` is the **baseline** of the text, not the `Y` *origin*.

#### Example using OnDraw override:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
{
    base.OnDraw(canvas); // call base here you want to draw the subclassed View content under your custom drawing
    using (var colorPaint = new Paint())
    {
        colorPaint.Color = Color.Rgb(255, 0, 0);
        colorPaint.TextSize = 30;
        canvas.DrawText("StackOverflow", 10, 30, colorPaint);
    }
    //base.OnDraw(canvas); // call base here you want to draw the subclassed View content over your custom drawing
}
```

#### OnDraw override on a Button subclass:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
{
    base.OnDraw(canvas);
    using (var colorPaint = new Paint())
    {
        colorPaint.Color = Color.Rgb(255, 0, 0);
        colorPaint.TextSize = 30;
        canvas.DrawText("StackOverflow", 12, 32, colorPaint);
        colorPaint.Color = Color.Rgb(255, 255, 255);
        canvas.DrawText("StackOverflow", 10, 30, colorPaint);
    }
}
```

[image]